# Output sequence incorrect after nested getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

In my project I've requirement to make a `rest API` call and fetch a `JSON` array in response.

Each array element will contain a item **'key'** (project key).
Response example is [here](http://www.mocky.io/v2/5b0ee6ad3200005400c19ca5).

Now I want to loop over this array, fetch project key, then a make another REST call to fetch details of each project.

I'm using below code to do this, but final output is not coming as expected.

```
var myOutput = [];
$.when (
    $.getJSON(projectListURL, function (data) {
        var compArr = data.components;
        for (i=0 ; i<compArr.length ; i++) {
            var projectKey = compArr[i].key;
            var projectName = compArr[i].name;

            var myURL = "http://myserver.com/projectdetails?projectkey=" + projectKey;
            $.getJSON(myURL, function (data) {

            }).then (function (data){
                console.log("myURL:" + myURL);
                console.log("name:" + projectName);
                var item = {};
                item["name"] = projectName;
                item["status"] = data.projectStatus.status;
                console.log(item);
                myOutput.push(item);
            });
        }
    })
).done (function () {
    console.log(myOutput);
});
```

I want myOutput to be something like:

```
[
    {name: "BaseProj", status: "OK"},
    {name: "Sudoku Project", status: "ERROR"},
    {name: "My Project", status: "WARN"}
]
```

But I'm getting:

```
[
    {name: "My Project", status: "OK"},
    {name: "My Project", status: "ERROR"},
    {name: "My Project", status: "WARN"}
]
```

Please suggest what should be the correct approach?

Thank You

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like: `item["name"] = data.projectName; `

Comment: `projectKey` and `projectName` are var scoped, which means they are scoped to the method, not the for each.  Either change them to `let` or use a closure for your looping

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the outer loop has finished before all the AJAX requests complete and their callbacks run. As such, the `projectKey`, `projectName` and `myURL` variables all hold the values of *the last iteration*.

To fix this you can use a closure around the inner calls to maintain the scope of the variables you pass in:

```js
var myOutput = [];
$.when(
  $.getJSON(projectListURL, function(data) {
    var compArr = data.components;
    for (i = 0; i < compArr.length; i++) {
      var projectKey = compArr[i].key;
      var projectName = compArr[i].name;
      var myURL = "http://myserver.com/projectdetails?projectkey=" + projectKey;

      (function(url, name) {
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

        }).then(function(data) {
          console.log("myURL:" + url);
          console.log("name:" + name);
          var item = {
            name: name,
            status: data.projectStatus.status
          };
          console.log(item);
          myOutput.push(item);
        });
      })(myURL, projectName);
    }
  })
).done(function() {
  console.log(myOutput);
});
```

Alternatively you can avoid the use of the closure and define the variables with the `let` keyword instead of `var`, but be aware that this will not work in < IE11.

Finally, note that in either case you can remove the callback handler function of the `$.getJSON` call as you're not using it, eg.:

```
$.getJSON(myURL).then(function(data) {
  // code...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rory. One question. What kind of variable will `myOutput` be? It's JSON.stringify(myOutput) comes blank - [ ]. And if I try myOutput[0] then its undefined. I want it to be a JSON. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @reiley I think that code does not only suffer from scoping issues but also from $.when().done finishing too soon (I think it finishes when first request is done). Better use something like: `$.getJSON(projectListURL).then($.when.apply($,result.map(resultToPromiseLike)` full code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9a19ktyo/1/)